# SQL Server - Set and use variable within select statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server query with a calculation that I would like to call 'my_long_calculation' which I use in several places within my query. The problem is that I do not know how this 'my_long_calculation' calculation can be stored into a variable for easier readability.

So this is the calculation:

```
(FLOOR(DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MINUTE, [table1].someInt, [table1].someDate)) / 1440.0) % 2) + 1
```

What it does is not important to this question. What matters is that this calculation is long to write.

Now I use this same calculation in several places within the query like this (Don't try to understand it, just note that there are several places where I use the same calculation, but I don't use it in the `SELECT` statement, only in the `JOIN` and `WHERE` statements:

```
SELECT
    [table1].ID
FROM 
    [table1]
INNER JOIN 
    [table2] ON [table2].someattribute = (FLOOR(DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MINUTE, [table1].someInt, [table1].someDate)) / 1440.0) % 2) + 1
INNER JOIN 
   [table3] ON [User].someattribute = (FLOOR(DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MINUTE, [table1].someInt, [table1].someDate)) / 1440.0) % 2) + 1
WHERE 
    (FLOOR(DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MINUTE, [table1].someInt, [table1].someDate)) / 1440.0) % 2) + 1 = 1
```

Now I would like to write this monstrosity above like this (by replacing all instances of the same calculation by a shorter name):

```
--my_long_calculation = (FLOOR(DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MINUTE, [table1].someInt, [table1].someDate)) / 1440.0) % 2) + 1

SELECT
    [table1].ID
FROM 
    [table1]
INNER JOIN 
    [table2] ON [table2].someattribute = my_long_calculation
INNER JOIN 
    [table3] ON [User].someattribute = my_long_calculation
WHERE 
    my_long_calculation = 1
```

Those two queries are the same, I just replaced the long calculation for the name/variable 'my_long_calculation'.

The second statement, of course, throws an error because 'my_long_calculation' is not defined. But how can I define and set a variable within a query in order to improve readability?

IMPORTANT: I don't want to return the long calculation by including it in the select statement. I only want to use it on the join and where statements

Comment: You should use subquery

Comment: uzi's suggestion is the correct one - one simple way would be to change your select to `select t1.id from (select *, my_long_calculation = floor(...) from table1) as t1 join table2 on table2.someattribute = t1.my_long_calculation` etc

Comment: Calculate your `my_long_calculation` in CTE (common table expression) and use in the main query.

Comment: _What it does is not important to this question._ No, it probably is important if you want an optimal solution. As written, your query will perform inefficiently since the optimizer cannot use any useful indexes to eliminate rows before the calculation. Perhaps a persisted computed column would help.

Answer (score 1):

Based from your comment which you have deleted, you wanted to use it inside each iteration. In this case, you need to create a scalar function instead,

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LongCalculation 
( 
   @firstParam INT,
   @secondParam DATETIME
) 
  RETURNS NUMERIC(10, 2)   -- specify correct data type here
  AS 
  BEGIN 
      --your logic here
  END 
GO
```

and use it inside your query,

```
SELECT
    [table1].ID
FROM 
    [table1]
    INNER JOIN [table2] ON [table2].someattribute =  dbo.LongCalculation([table1].someInt, [table1].someDate)
    INNER JOIN [table3] ON [User].someattribute =  dbo.LongCalculation([table1].someInt, [table1].someDate)
WHERE 
     dbo.LongCalculation([table1].someInt, [table1].someDate) = 1
```

Comment: Your `set` clause will not work. Since it includes `someInt` column from `[table1]` table

Comment: @uzi I know, that's what I stated in the next line.

Comment: I don't think either of those queries will produce the desired result, actually. The first is incorrect syntax, the second just doesn't do what you might think it does.

Comment: @JuanCastano then you are looking for a scalar function and not declaring and setting a variable.

Comment: @ZLK the first one shows how to use `DELCARE`, the second one shows how to set the value inside a `SELECT` statement. of course this doesn't do what the user wants. there maybe filtering as well as other join.

Comment: @JohnWoo perhaps, I am not sure if I need to use a variable or scalar, I am certain I want to rename the long calculation but uncertain on how to do so. I'll try your suggestion, not sure if it will work.

Comment: @JuanCastano I added sample code block to create function and how to use it.

Comment: The `DECLARE` syntax is fine. The `SET` syntax will _not_ work, because you cannot set from a table like that. As for the second one, that actually will do nothing specifically because before the query `@my_long_calculation` is null therefore it will select nothing with a where clause that says `where @my_long_calculation = 1`. In short, your suggestions are not the right way of tackling the question and have rather serious issues apart from that. A function is also unnecessary (and potentially unwieldy for larger tables). Just use a subquery when selecting from table1.

Comment: It worked for me. Although I did some modifications: on `--your logic here` I typed `RETURN(...)` the '...' is the long calculation. And I also learnt that I have to `DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS` every time I want to re-run the whole query

Comment: @JohnWoo Could you delete the first two codes on your answer pls? I had to use a function because your first suggestion (using a variable) did not work

Answer (score 1):

Best approach will be to crate a Scalar Valued function like following. By using function you don't have to write same formula everywhere. It is more maintainable.

```
CREATE function [dbo].[ufn_Calculate]
(
@someInt INT,
@someDate DATETIME
)
returns DECIMAL(15,2)

AS

Begin

DECLARE @CalculationOutput DECIMAL(15,2)
SELECT @CalculationOutput = (FLOOR(DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MINUTE, @someInt, @someDate)) / 1440.0) % 2) + 1
RETURN @CalculationOutput
End
GO
```

Now you can use it like following in your queries.

```
 SELECT
    [table1].ID
FROM 
    [table1]
    INNER JOIN [table2] ON [table2].someattribute = [dbo].[ufn_Calculate]([table1].someInt,[table1].someDate)
    INNER JOIN [table3] ON [User].someattribute = [dbo].[ufn_Calculate]([table1].someInt,[table1].someDate)
WHERE 
    [dbo].[ufn_Calculate]([table1].someInt,[table1].someDate) = 1
```

Comment: It is actually the same answer as @JohnWoo's. But this-one is easier to understand. Thanks

Comment: When I posted, answer was something else :). Later it was updated